# Making independent Slick queries inside of single Play action

Tags: scala, playframework, slick, slick-3.0

I have async Play `Action`, that retrieves data from the datbase, using Slick. And Slick, obviously, uses `Future`s to avoid blocking:

```
def show(id: Long) = Action.async {
 db.run(entities.filter(_.id === id).result.headOption).map {
   case None => templateFor("NEW_OBJECT")
   case Some(x) => Ok(x)
 }
def templateFor(code: String): Future[Result] = {
  db.run(templates.filter(_.code === code).result.headOption).map {
    case None => InternalServerError("No template")
    case Some(x) => Ok(x)
  }
}
```

The problem is that call to `templateFor()` returns `Future`, so the whole `Action` returns `Future[Future[Result]]` which is not what expected by Play. So, i would like to get rid of that nested `Future`. The simple way to do it is to `Await` for it's completion, but i would like to avoid unnecessary blocking. It would be nice if i would be able to take `Future[Result]` produced by `templateFor()` function and return it intact from my `Action`, thus replacing the outer `Future` with it.

Comment: `flatMap` it :)

Comment: As @ipoteka said:  https://cdn.meme.am/cache/instances/folder331/500x/67321331.jpg :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `flatMap` for that,

For any monandic strutcture such as `Future[T]`, `flatMap` takes a function of type `T => SomeOtherMonad[K]`, applies that function on all elements if monad and then flattens them to gives you `Future[K]`.

```
def show(id: Long) = Action.async {
  db.run(entities.filter(_.id === id).result.headOption).flatMap {
    case None => templateFor("NEW_OBJECT")
    case Some(x) => Future(Ok(x))
  }

  def templateFor(code: String): Future[Result] =
    db.run(templates.filter(_.code === code).result.headOption).map {
      case None => InternalServerError("No template")
      case Some(x) => Ok(x)
    }
}
```